# nextjs dynamic routing problem with spaces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, next.js, pathname

I meet a problem to access dynamic routes through a product name from my API when the name has spaces. I have no problem accessing routes when the product name is just one word.

utils/api.js

```
export async function getProduct(name) {
  const products = await fetchAPI(`/books?name=${name}`);
  return products?.[0];
}
```

pages/books/[name].js

```
// This function gets called at build time
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Call an external API endpoint to get products
  const products = await getProducts();
  // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
  const paths = products.map((product) => `/books/${product.name}`)
  // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
  // { fallback: false } means other routes should 404.
  return { paths, fallback: false }
}
```

/components/Catalogue.js

```
<Link href='/books/[name]' as={`/books/${_product.name}`}>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) or [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). This encodes special characters like spaces to ensure that they are not misinterpretad by the browser / server.
Your code should look like this:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const products = await getProducts();
  const paths = products.map((product) => `/books/${encodeURIComponent(product.name)}`)
  return { paths, fallback: false }
}

<Link href='/books/[name]' as={`/books/${encodeURIComponent(_product.name)}`}>
```